# How does the : param in a query work

Tags: apex, soql

I always thought that : was a required when writing a SOQL query, lately I have been seeing people post queries with or without :

I tested this in DEV console and it works in both cases. Have I been wrong all this time about the : (or) salesforce relax the rules on : in a query

```
List <user> userList = [SELECT id,name FROM User where Isactive = true limit 1]; // worrks 
List <user> userList1 = [SELECT id,name FROM User where Isactive =: true limit 1]; // works
```

Pretty basic but would be a huge help if someone can clarify!!!

Comment: Not directly related but it never hurts to know where these ":binding" ideas come from and why they're best invention since sliced bread: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement, https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colon `:` is used to bind Apex variables in queries.

```
 String name = 'Bacon';
 List<Food__c> foods = [SELECT Id FROM Food__c WHERE Name = :name];
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
 List<Food__c> foods = [SELECT Id FROM Food__c WHERE Name = :'Bacon'];
```

Which is the same as:

```
 List<Food__c> foods = [SELECT Id FROM Food__c WHERE Name = 'Bacon'];
```

It can also be used to bind Lists and Sets:

```
 List<String> foodNames = new List<String> { 'Bacon', 'Eggs' };
 List<Food__c> foods = [SELECT Id FROM Food__c WHERE Name IN :foodNames];
```

Comment: ah I see it now, basic but never understood in the first place :). Thanks

Comment: Moar Bacon! Nyom